# htmlentities not working with ° (&deg;)

Tags: php

having some trouble but not getting where it is, i want to save ° char as `&deg;` in DB

```
//$_POST['group'] = "1° BF"

$group = htmlentities($_POST['group'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

//$group should be "1&deg; BF" but still shows as "1° BF"
```

Document charset is defined as UTF-8 too

Comment: What does "having some trouble" mean?

Comment: It does work: https://eval.in/183528 Are you sure that `$_POST['group']` is encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: The page which has the form is UTF-8 encoded if is that what you mean

Comment: Why in the world would you want to store a perfectly fine character as garbled "&deg;" in the database?!

Comment: Is data in $_POST['group'] encoded in UTF-8

Comment: sometimes users input `&deg;` but others `&ordm;` depends on keyboard and OS, i think. Also i should always use htmlentities() before letting anything hit the DB right?

Comment: @user3901148 No, a user usually never inputs HTML entities such as `&deg;`. I would store it as-is in the DB. Do you want to output it later as raw text or HTML? You must be careful when outputting HTML since the user could supply malicious HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i finally got it. as noted above i am actually storing as `°` in DB, i needed to make all chars the same, because i had a mix of °, º, ª (all imported from some ancient DBF).
What do you think about this?

```
//$group = 1° BF, or 1&ordm; BF, or 1&ordf; BF

//check var length here
$group = htmlentities($_POST['group'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$group = str_replace("&deg;", "°", $group);
$group = str_replace("&ordm;", "°", $group);
$group = str_replace("&ordf;", "°", $group);
$group = str_replace("|", "°", $group);

//$group = "1° BF", ready to go to DB.
```

edit:
following deceze sugestion

Comment: I made a suggested edit to your post because I think it's displaying the actual character of the HTML entities instead of the HTML entity. Please disregard the edit suggestion if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Why not `str_replace('º', '°', $group)`...?